# How to create Outlook email and resize all images

Tags: excel, vba, image, outlook, resize

The Excel macro below works great, except that images in the Excel range that gets pasted into the body gets resized (most of them to 55%).

I can't figure out what is wrong.

If I manually copy the exact same range and paste it into an email, the image stays intact.

```
Sub mailpaste()


Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object
Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range

    Application.Range("Report").copy

    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    With ActiveSheet
    Set rngTo = .Range("AA12")
    Set rngSubject = .Range("AA15")
    End With

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .To = rngTo.Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = rngSubject.Value
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 1
        oRng.Paste
        .Display
    End With


    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*You are already using Word object so work with InlineShapes property height/Width of an inline shape*

*Example*

```
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set wdDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

    With OutMail
        .BodyFormat = 2
        .To = rngTo.Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = rngSubject.Value
        .Display

         wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture

         With wdDoc
            .InlineShapes(1).Height = 130
            .InlineShapes(1).Width = 130
         End With


    End With
```