# Pasted Range into Outlook Zoomed Out

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a code which copies and pastes a range into the body of an outlook email.
The issue is when it's pasting the range into outlook it's zooming in the range and making it really big.
Consequently, sometimes this email is printed and it's printing over 2 pages due to the size.

I've searched online and made some changes to some settings in Outlook but nothing seems to make any difference.

```
Private Sub SendEmail_Click()


Dim FormWks As Worksheet
Dim DataWks As Worksheet
Dim myRng As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim iCtr As Long
Dim myAddr As Variant
Dim lOrders As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set FormWks = Sheets("Email HS Del")
Set DataWks = Sheets("Quote Database")

myAddr = Array("G9", "G10", "G11", "G12", "C14", "B48", "B49", "B50", "B51", "B52", 
"B53", "B54", "B25", "C25", "D25", "E25", "F25", "G25", "H25", "I25", "A49", "A50", 
"B26", "C26", "D26", "E26", "F26", "G26", "H26", "I26", "A51", "A52", "B27", "C27", 
"D27", "E27", "F27", "G27", "H27", "I27", "A53", "A54", "B28", "C28", "D28", "E28", 
"F28", "G28", "H28", "I28", "A55", "A56", "B29", "C29", "D29", "E29", "F29", "G29", 
"H29", "I29", "A57", "A58", "I30", "H31", "H32", "H33", "A60", "A61", "A62", "A63", 
"A64", "D37", "D38", "D39", "D40", "B55", "B56", "B57", "B58", "B59", "B60", "A65", 
"A66", "A67", "A68", "A69")

 With DataWks
 Set myRng = .Range("B3", _
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
End With

For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
With myCell
If IsEmpty(.Offset(0, -1)) Then

 Else

   .Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
  For iCtr = LBound(myAddr) _
    To UBound(myAddr)
    FormWks.Range(myAddr(iCtr)).Value _
      = myCell.Offset(0, iCtr).Value
  Next iCtr
  Application.Calculate
  lOrders = lOrders + 1
End If
End With

Next


 Sheets("Email HS Del").Visible = True
 Sheets("Email HS Del").Select
 Range("A1:I35").Select



 ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

 With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
  .Introduction = "Please see new order below, Thanks"
  .Item.To = Me.ComboBox1.Value
  .Item.Subject = "Order re Estone Personal Credit Ltd/HomeSmile"
  .Item.Send
 End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = False




Sheets("Email HS Del").Visible = False

Sheets("Quote Database").Select
 Range("P1:R1").ClearContents
 MsgBox "Your order has been emailed"


Unload Me

End Sub
```

This is how it's pasting into the email body:

[image: rangepaste]

This is how it looks if trying to print

[image: printedpastedrange]

The range in my excel sheet is on 1 page.

Any help would be great.

Comment: If I am not wrong, this usually happens when you have used "Page Break Preview" or something similar to adjust the margins in Excel to fit content in 1 page. In such a case, Outlook will show you limited data in Print Preview. When you are in draft mode, I doubt you can do anything about it a it uses Memo style while printing. However once the email is sent, the recepient can open the email in a browser (Actions -> View In Browser) and then print from there using "Fit to printable area".

Comment: If you replace Excel's `.MailEnvelope` with Outlook then default settings may work. If not see [How to create Outlook email and resize all images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713341/how-to-create-outlook-email-and-resize-all-images)